# Using logical operator in knockout conditional if binding

Tags: knockout.js, conditional-statements, logical-operators

```
<!-- ko if:name == 'Setup' || name == 'Appeals' -->
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret">/span>/button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

I am trying to show a button with a dropdown only when the name property contains the value "Setup" or "Appeals" but it does not work. Can we use logical operator in above knockout if binding ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When you are using a conditional statement inside of your binding remember that you need to 'get' the value -

```
<!-- ko if: name() === 'Setup' || name() === 'Appeals' -->
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret">/span>/button>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: don't know if this is explained in the documentation, well.. i haven't found it. But is **really** important

Comment: @colthreepv, property ''name'' is an observable, so it needs to be called as function in the view - name().

Comment: If you want to do `name() !== 'Setup'`, you can use [`ifnot:`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html)